# No package 'opencv' found

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, pkg-config

I'm trying out this [github repository](https://github.com/prouast/heartbeat), one of the requirements is to have opencv 3.1

when I run `pip list` I have opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python both version 4.7.0.68

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 Heartbeat.cpp opencv.cpp RPPG.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o Heartbeat
```

but when I run the above I get the error below

Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'opencv' found

Comment: opencv 3.1 is not a requirement. author states that "it works with" that version. doesn't mean you can't try a more recent one. -- if you have multiple opencv-python packages installed (you do), that is an error and will fail. remove them all, install exactly one. -- opencv-python packages do not give you the ability to compile C++ code that uses OpenCV. they only give you the ability to run python code that uses OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

Please use opencv4 instead of opencv. So your command will look like:

```
g++ -std=c++11 Heartbeat.cpp opencv.cpp RPPG.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` -o Heartbeat
```

It should work.

Comment: thanks, this helped out then I used chatGPT to debug the rest.